# Jqplot dateaxisrendrer issue for plotting multiline chart, last 30 minutes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, charts, jqplot

I am plotting tickinterval dynamically.. eg. last hour, last 24 hour, last 7 days...

For days and 24 hour i am good. Problem comes when i try to re-plot it for last hour. Dateaxisrender renders chart from 12:00 midnight. I tried using min date as close as my data but still no luck. i am providing tickinterval as milliseconds...

Is that anything i am overlooking here..? thanks in advance...[image]

Note: 
mainArray = data
dFormat = string format for date time

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot(div, mainArray, {
                        title:chartValue[1],
                        seriesDefaults: {
                            lineWidth:1,
                            markerOptions: { show:true, size:3 },
                            rendererOptions: {
                                smooth: true
                            }
                        },
                        axesDefaults: {
                            labelOptions:{textColor:'#313233', fontSize:'11px',fontWeight:'Bold', fontFamily:'Arial'}
                        },
                        axes:{
                            xaxis:{
                                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                rendererOptions:{
                                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                                    tickInset:0
                                },
                                //tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                                tickOptions:{
                                    autoscale:true,
                                    fontSize:'10px',
                                    fontFamily:'Arial',
                                    angle:-90,
                                    formatString: dFormat
                                },
                                //min: minDate,
                                //max: maxDate,
                                tickInterval:timeInterval
                            },
                            yaxis:{
                                min: 0,
                                max: maxV.length > 1 ? parseInt(maxV) + ((parseInt(maxV)/10)): parseInt(maxV)+2,
                                tickOptions: {
                                    formatString: '%d',
                                    fontSize:'10px',
                                    fontFamily:'Arial',
                                    showGridline: true,
                                    showLabel: true
                                },
                                base: Math.E,
                                forceTickAt0: true
                            }
                        },

                        legend: {
                            show: true,
                            labels: legendNames,
                            //placement: 'outsideGrid'
                            renderer:$.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                            location: 'ne',     // compass direction, nw, n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w.
                            xoffset: 10,        // pixel offset of the legend box from the x (or x2) axis.
                            yoffset: 10        // pixel offset of the legend box from the y (or y2) axis.
                        },

                        cursor:{
                            show:true,
                            style:'auto',
                            followMouse:true,
                            zoom:true,
                            looseZoom:true,
                            showTooltip:false
                        }

                    });
```

Data Passed = [[[18:10:02,1],[18:10:12,1],[18:10:13
,2],[18:14:10,1],[18:14:15,1],[18:14:20,1],][[18:15:25,1],[18:15:30,1]]] like  that

Comment: can you share the data that's being supplied to generate this chart? ta!

Comment: i have added data which is passed to jqplot...

Comment: I don't see why min & max didn't work. did you change tickInterval when you set them?

Comment: any chance you could set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: tickinterval is fixed depends on date/time, means its calculated dymanically....

Comment: it had use jsfiddle but not get solution any more.........